# Installation failed due to invalid APK file! (when attempting to run emulator) Also fails when attempting to export

Tags: java, android, eclipse, export, apk

I'm unable to run my app on an emulator (or export to an APK) I really have no idea what's going on... hopefully someone has come across this before or can interpret what is happening!

Judging from the last line of the LOGCAT I need to split it into different threads - but I have no idea how to get started!

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

LOGCAT:

```
03-03 00:43:49.098: D/AndroidRuntime(1003): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START      com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
03-03 00:43:49.098: D/AndroidRuntime(1003): CheckJNI is ON
03-03 00:43:49.158: D/dalvikvm(1003): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-03 00:43:49.168: D/dalvikvm(1003): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-03 00:43:49.218: D/dalvikvm(1003): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-03 00:43:49.218: D/dalvikvm(1003): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-03 00:43:49.748: D/ExchangeService(647): Received deviceId from Email app: null
03-03 00:43:49.748: D/ExchangeService(647): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
03-03 00:43:50.408: D/AndroidRuntime(1003): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
03-03 00:43:50.508: W/PackageParser(512): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of     /data/local/tmp/Linking Manager.apk
03-03 00:43:50.508: W/PackageParser(512): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
03-03 00:43:50.508: W/PackageParser(512):   at     android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
03-03 00:43:50.508: W/PackageParser(512):   at     android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
03-03 00:43:50.508: W/PackageParser(512):   at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:455)
03-03 00:43:50.508: W/PackageParser(512):   at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:733)
03-03 00:43:50.508: W/PackageParser(512):   at     com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java    :171)
03-03 00:43:50.508: W/PackageParser(512):   at     com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:110)
03-03 00:43:50.508: W/PackageParser(512):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
03-03 00:43:50.508: W/PackageParser(512):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-03 00:43:50.508: W/DefContainer(512): Failed to parse package
03-03 00:43:50.518: W/ActivityManager(292): No content provider found for permission revoke:     file:///data/local/tmp/Linking Manager.apk
03-03 00:43:50.698: D/dalvikvm(292): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 27% free 5565K/7544K, paused     10ms+18ms, total 181ms
03-03 00:43:50.778: D/AndroidRuntime(1003): Shutting down VM
03-03 00:43:50.838: D/dalvikvm(1003): GC_CONCURRENT freed 119K, 21% free 477K/600K, paused     3ms+1ms, total 53ms
03-03 00:43:50.838: D/jdwp(1003): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
03-03 00:43:50.838: D/dalvikvm(1003): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-03 00:43:54.848: D/ExchangeService(647): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
03-03 00:43:54.848: D/ExchangeService(647): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp =     false, running = false
03-03 00:43:54.877: D/ExchangeService(647): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp =     true, running = false
03-03 00:43:54.887: W/ActivityManager(292): Unable to start service Intent {     act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-03 00:43:54.887: D/ExchangeService(647): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
03-03 00:43:54.907: W/ActivityManager(292): Unable to start service Intent {     act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has     leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d09ac8 that     was originally bound here
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service     com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection     com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d09ac8 that was originally bound here
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>    (LoadedApk.java:969)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-03 00:43:54.937: E/ActivityThread(647):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647): null
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service     com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d09ac8 that was originally bound here
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>    (LoadedApk.java:969)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at     android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at     android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at     android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at     com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at     com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-03 00:43:54.947: E/StrictMode(647):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-03 00:43:54.957: W/ActivityManager(292): Unbind failed: could not find connection for     android.os.BinderProxy@41003258
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has     leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d42668 that     was originally bound here
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service     com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d42668 that was originally bound here
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>    (LoadedApk.java:969)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at     com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-03 00:43:54.977: E/ActivityThread(647):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647): null
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d42668 that was originally bound here
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>    (LoadedApk.java:969)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-03 00:43:54.998: E/StrictMode(647):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-03 00:43:54.998: W/ActivityManager(292): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4100c758
03-03 00:44:00.308: I/Choreographer(355): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much   work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your apk is `invalid`, when the apk that's currently installed is **differently signed.**
Thus I suggest

1. Uninstall the old application
2. Rebuild the project
3. Reinstall the apk

Comment: Awesome! What exactly do you mean by rebuild the project? (I want to make sure I do this correctly so I'm not just shooting in the dark - should I create a new project and copy over the source code until it's rebuilt?)

Comment: I uninstalled the app on the emulator, unchecked rebuild automatically, cleaned the file, and rechecked rebuild automatically (as several sites suggest) and reinstalled the app and it still fails.

- is this the method you were suggesting? (it's still not working)

Comment: It didn't seem to resolve the issue. I'm still getting errors regarding doing too much work on the main thread.

(New Log Cat File)

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kxyBmlu1zdm1xS1YR8Hg4fRYaYMx2kIoryAYQxEGn4A/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

From the Logs It Seems like AndroidManifest.xml is missing . Check for the file presence . 
And if you are using eclipse do  Project/clean . And provide more info like the contents of  AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I tried project/clean (no dice) 

Here is a copy of my manifest file:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UftH_biaQbPRhBzyvoAF43xeXeut7rPl9RL0zrqZqlQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you see if something is missing or incorrect in the AndroidManifest.xml? It's located in the root folder as it should be so I'm really not sure what is going on.

Comment: Check for the file permissions .

Comment: The read only button was semi-filled (as in some of the files within the folder are read only but not others) I cleared it, saved it - came back and it's semi filled again (I guess some folders/files cannot be changed to not be read only) however I checked the android manifest and it's not read only at all... (but I still can't launch the app - and my deadline was yesterday so I'm kinda freaking out! Any help is GREATLY appreciated!)

Comment: Now I'm noticing something strange... I uninstalled it and reinstalled it and it shows up under applications in the settings menu but never appears when I open all apps from the homescreen/launcher

Comment: Nor does it launch automatically as it should.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need to enable MultiThreading so it will stop crashing and giving these errors... can anyone suggest how/where in the source code to do this?